# Replication Monitor Show red X but the replication is working as well

Tags: sql-server, replication, monitor

I setup my replication in SQL Server 2008 R2, but today my Replication Monitor is only show red `X` although this is working as well.

picshort:

http://upanh.biz/images/2015/01/27/red_x_in_replication_monitor.png
[image]

Sorry I do not have enough reputation to post images

Can somebody help me?

Comment: If you look at the history of the publication in the replication monitor, are there any recent errors?

Comment: I just checked no any error in history.:(

Comment: Hi , @Steven i have same issue here , can you tell me how did you resolve it?

Comment: Restart and the issue go away, I don't know why, but maybe that's a bug of MS